# can't save encrypted password in mongodb using node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to save the username and encrypted password of the user in the database for user registration. But for some reason, the username is saved in the database but not the encrypted password. The password field is empty.

```
//jshint esversion:6
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const encrypt = require("mongoose-encryption");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB", {useNewUrlParser: true});

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    email: String,
    password: String
});

const secret = "Thisisourlittlesecret.";
userSchema.plugin(encrypt, { secret: secret, encryptedFields: ["password"] });

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render("home");
});

app.get("/register", function(req, res) {
    res.render("register");
});

app.get("/login", function(req, res) {
    res.render("login");
});

app.post("/register", function(req, res) {
    const newUser = new User({
        email: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    });

    newUser.save()
        .then(() => {
            res.render("secrets");
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server started on port 3000.");
});
```

There is no error on the page so I don't know what to fix.

Comment: Just a note: Passwords should be hashed, not encrypted.

Answer (score -1):

1. Temporarily remove encryption from the schema and try saving password as plain text
2. Logging req.body.password and see the coming data, maybe some issues with body-parser

Comment: Without encryption the password gets saved in the database.

Comment: Passwords should not be encrypted anyway. Use a password hash!